# Loading the data of two files as Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Load the data in the two files as Pandas Dataframe (you should use the following parameters: index_col=0, parse_dates=True). You should use a for loop and put the Dataframe to Dict object (the key of Dict is a ticker: BTC, ETH) whose name is dfs. You should begin with the following code:

```
tickers = ['BTC', 'ETH']
dfs = {}
for ticker in tickers:
dfs[ticker] =
```

---

My Code:

input

```
df = pd.read_csv('BTC.csv', 'ETH.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

output

```
Date,Log_ret
1-Jan-19,
2-Jan-19,0.016764241
3-Jan-19,-0.024485473
4-Jan-19,0.005960876
5-Jan-19,-0.004559779
...
17-Sep-21,-0.009790588
18-Sep-21,0.021423674
19-Sep-21,-0.022356795
20-Sep-21,-0.097027196
21-Sep-21,-0.030213521
995 rows × 0 columns
```

I seem to get only the data from BTC.csv file. Would I have to look into concatenate two strings to get both sets of data into the DataFrame?

Some insight/clarification on this would be super helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Note that when using libraries like pandas, it is important that you read the online documentation for the functions you are using. They explain what parameters they expect at which positions, and other conventions they may use. It may seem daunting at first, but it will save you from a lot of errors down the line

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this line

```py
df = pd.read_csv('BTC.csv', 'ETH.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

is the following:
[read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) reads **one** CSV file at a time. The file name should be passed as the first argument (as you do), but the rest of the arguments do different things.

You want to do the following:

```py
df_BTC = pd.read_csv('BTC.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
df_ETH = pd.read_csv('ETH.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

In what you have written, 'ETH.csv' is not interpreted as the filename to be opened. Since it is the second argument you passed, it corresponds to `read_csv()`'s second parameter, i.e. `sep` (see the link above).
As a result, you function call, opens (only) BTC.csv, and instead of splitting cols by the delimiter string ",", it splits them by the (non-existent) delimiter "ETH.csv". So all of the data in each row are assumed to belong on the same (first) column, which is treated as an index, due to having set `index_col=0`.
This is why you are seeing: `"995 rows × 0 columns"` when examining `df`.